# Flex 4.6 push a specific view with a list item?

Tags: apache-flex, list, view, flash-builder

I am working on a Flex 4.6 Mobile project and am trying to use a list to navigate views from a menu view that has been set up.

I'm finding tutorials from Adobe, but most involve changing to the same view and just altering data based on which list item you clicked.  What I am actually trying to do is , depending on which list item you click on, you get a unrelated view pushed in, different views completely per list item.  Also, did I go about this the wrong way?  I understand there are many different ways to navigate the views, with buttons, tabs, etc.  But this is something that has been asked for.  Example of my current list:

```
    <s:List id="toolsList" x="10" y="284" width="255" height="197" borderVisible="false"
        color="black" downColor="#00764C" fontSize="16" fontWeight="bold"
        skinClass="view.skins.ListSkin" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>  
            <renderers:StyledIconItemRenderer labelField="label" iconField="icon"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>       
    <s:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:Object label="Settings" icon="@Embed('resources/arrow.png')"/>
        <fx:Object label="Fault Current Search" icon="@Embed('resources/arrow.png')"/>
        <fx:Object label="Share Picture" icon="@Embed('resources/arrow.png')"/>
        <fx:Object label="System Info" icon="@Embed('resources/arrow.png')"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>    
</s:List>
```

So, based on above example I would like to click on the "Settings" list item and get my settings view, then when I "pop" the settings view, I will go back to the menu and if I click the "Share Picture" list item, then I get that specific view, and so forth.

I am not really asking anyone to write code for me here, but maybe even point me in the right direction of a online example that maybe I haven't found yet.

Thank you in advance for any consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store some data on each item in the `ArrayCollection` about which view it should navigate to, then you could write a change event handler for the list that reads this data and will push the appropriate view.

For example, add the fully qualified class name of the view that each item should go to:

```
<s:ArrayCollection>
    <fx:Object label="Settings" icon="@Embed('resources/arrow.png')" viewClass="com.whatever.SettingsClass/>
    ...
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

Then add a click handler to the list:

```
<s:List id="theList" change="onSelectedItemChange()" />

private function onSelectedItemChange():void
{
    var className:String = theList.selectedItem.viewClass;
    var viewClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
    ViewNavigatorApplication.navigator.pushView(viewClass);
}
```